# Python exit a threading function from inside another function

Tags: python, multithreading, function

I want to exit a threading function from inside another function. Here is an example:

```
from threading import *
from time import *
import keyboard


def ExampleFunction():
    while True:
        print('The Example function is running.')  # do something in a loop
        sleep(1)

def ExitFunction():
    print('ExitFunction was called.')
    keyboard.wait('f8')  # wait until f8 was pressed
    # do whatever it takes to exit the ExampleFunction

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=ExampleFunction).start()
    Thread(target=ExitFunction).start()
```

Comment: maybe use `global` variable `running = True` and in `ExampleFunction` use  `while running:` and in other function use `running = False`. Eventually functions should use `queue` to send information and `ExampleFunction` should check in every loop `if not queue.empty: msg = queue.get() ;  if msg == "exit": break` and `ExitFunction` could send `queue.put("exit")`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `global` variable `running = True` and in `ExampleFunction` use `while running:` and in other function use `running = False`

```
from threading import *
from time import *
import keyboard

# global variable
running = True

def ExampleFunction():
    print("ExampleFunction: start")
    
    while running:
        #print('The Example function is running.')  # do something in a loop
        sleep(1)
        
    print("ExampleFunction: exit")

def ExitFunction():
    global running  # inform function to use global variable instead of local variable

    print('ExitFunction: start')
    
    keyboard.wait('f8')  # wait until f8 was pressed

    running = False
    
    print('ExitFunction: sleep')
    sleep(5)  # simulate other code
    
    print('ExitFunction: end')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = Thread(target=ExampleFunction)
    t1.start()
    
    t2 = Thread(target=ExitFunction)
    t2.start()
    
    t1.join()  # wait for end of `ExampleFunction`
    t2.join()  # wait for end of `ExitFunction`
```

---

The same way you can use `threading.Event` and it doesn't need to use `global running` because it will not use `=` inside `ExitFunction`

```
from threading import *
from time import *
import keyboard

# global variable
running = Event()
running.set()  # set `True`

def ExampleFunction():
    print("ExampleFunction: start")
    
    while running.is_set():
        #print('The Example function is running.')  # do something in a loop
        sleep(1)
        
    print("ExampleFunction: exit")

def ExitFunction():
    print('ExitFunction: start')
    
    keyboard.wait('f8')  # wait until f8 was pressed

    running.clear()  # set `False`
    
    print('ExitFunction: sleep')
    sleep(5)  # simulate other code
    
    print('ExitFunction: end')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    t1 = Thread(target=ExampleFunction)
    t1.start()
    
    t2 = Thread(target=ExitFunction)
    t2.start()
    
    t1.join()  # wait for end of `ExampleFunction`
    t2.join()  # wait for end of `ExitFunction`
```

---

You may even send `Event` as argument in `Thread`

```
from threading import *
from time import *
import keyboard

# global variable
running = Event()
running.set()  # set `True`

def ExampleFunction(running):
    print("ExampleFunction: start")
    
    while running.is_set():
        #print('The Example function is running.')  # do something in a loop
        sleep(1)
        
    print("ExampleFunction: exit")

def ExitFunction(running):
    print('ExitFunction: start')
    
    keyboard.wait('f8')  # wait until f8 was pressed

    running.clear()  # set `False`
    
    print('ExitFunction: sleep')
    sleep(5)  # simulate other code
    
    print('ExitFunction: end')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    t1 = Thread(target=ExampleFunction, args=(running,))  # `args` needs `,` inside `()` to create `tuple`
    t1.start()
    
    t2 = Thread(target=ExitFunction, args=(running,))  # `args` needs `,` inside `()` to create `tuple`
    t2.start()
    
    t1.join()  # wait for end of `ExampleFunction`
    t2.join()  # wait for end of `ExitFunction`
```

---

**BTW:**

If you would use `multiprocessing` then you could [kill()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.kill) other process.

Comment: Could you give me an example how i could do it with the multiprocessing package and the kill() method?

Comment: you have example in documentation for [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). It uses `Process` instead of `Thread`. But `kill` may create one problem - it stops process at one and if it makes some calculations or writes data in file then it not finish it, and it may not write all data in file, and you get broken file.